# Spring Security + Spring Remoting + Swing

Tags: spring, swing, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a spring based application secured by spring-security. Services are exposed through HttpInvoker and I want to use those services from a Swing based client.

I know how to use those remote services in Swing client through HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean. But I cannot find a good example to handle authentication from my swing based client. Can you guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it done, and publishing the answer here to help anyone having the same issue.

In your swing client setup the HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean as follows.

```
@Bean
public HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean invoker(AuthenticationSimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor httpInvokerRequestExecutor) {
    HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean invoker = new HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean();
    invoker.setServiceUrl(<URL_HERE>);
    invoker.setServiceInterface(DeliveryService.class);
    invoker.setHttpInvokerRequestExecutor(httpInvokerRequestExecutor);
    return invoker;
}
```

You also need to have a AuthenticationSimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor bean as below, in your client.

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationSimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor httpInvokerRequestExecutor() {
    return new AuthenticationSimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor();
}
```

And,after you have you have to set your username and password in your local SecurityContext as below.

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(<Username>, <Password>));
```

All set, now you can retrieve the Service beans follows.

```
<ServiceInterface> service = context.getBean(<ServiceInterface>.class);
```

You also have to enabled HTTP Basic Authentication in your server's security configuration. Otherwise you will get StreamCorruptedException.

Comment: As further reference: I had to disbale CSRF on the server, otherwise it would always return HTTP 401.